# Confusion about changing frames of reference in loop integral

Tags: quantum-field-theory, kinematics, reference-frames, feynman-diagrams

I have what seems to be a pretty stupid problem I've been stuck on for days.

Consider a three-point, one-loop interaction like the image below. For example, it could be a higher-order contribution to Compton scattering.

[image: A three-point, one-loop interaction]

I want to calculate a loop integral (which could be any combination of the external $q$ and $l$ and the internal $k$) over $k$. It can be performed in many ways but in any case, I will have to integrate over $k$ in the entire momentum space. I am not getting the results I am looking for, and I suspect an issue with my formulation of frames of reference for the problem. In the following, I show in a very simple way that two different frames of reference give different results, which should be unphysical.

The assumptions I make are the following:

**Case 1:**

- The incoming particle is at rest, $l=(m,0,0,0)$.
- The incoming photon is on the $z$ axis, $q=(q_0,0,0,q_4)$. Through conservation of momentum and taking the photon's virtuality, $Q^2=-q^2>0$ as a free parameter, this can be written as $q=(\frac{Q^2}{2m},0,0,\frac{Q}{2}\sqrt{4+\frac{Q^2}{4m^2}})$.

  - Derivation of the above, for completeness: conservation of momentum gives us $(l+q)^2=(l')^2$. Expanding, we get $l^2+2 l\cdot q+q^2=(l')^2$, but both external particles are on shell, so $l^2=(l')^2=m^2$ and the conservation is reduced to $l\cdot q=-q^2/2=Q^2/2$. Finally, from the assumptions above, $l\cdot q=mq_0\Rightarrow mq_0=Q^2/2\Rightarrow q_0=Q^2/(2m)$. The $q_4$ term is selected so that $q\cdot q=-Q^2$.

**Case 2:**

- The external particles have opposite momenta, $l=(\sqrt{m^2+p^2},0,0,p)$ and $l'=(\sqrt{m^2+p^2},0,0,-p)$, where the first terms are the respective energies of the particles.
- The incoming photon must then (by momentum conservation, since $l+q=l'$) have momentum $q=(2\sqrt{m^2+p^2},0,0,0)$. $p$ is selected to give the correct squared momenta once more: $p^2=-\frac{Q^2}{4}-m^2$.

**Both cases:**

- $k$ is a dummy vector to be integrated upon, so this is left as $k=(k_0,k_1,k_2,k_3)$. **This is where I feel I'm getting something wrong, but I don't know how else I could approach the problem. Should $k$ have some pre-described form?**

**The problem:**

Obviously, while the squared momenta are correct ($q^2=-Q^2,l^2=m^2$), the dot products $q\cdot k$ and $l\cdot k$ are different in the two frames. For example, $q\cdot k=$ either $\frac{Q}{2m}\left(k_1 Q-k_4\sqrt{4m^2+Q^2}\right)$ or just $k_4Q$, which are by definition different since $k_i$ are essentially free variables to be integrated over. My instinct is that the dot products should be invariant. After numerically integrating various expressions over $k$, I get different final results for the two frames, so something must indeed be wrong.

Comment: When I took QFT, we did loop integrals *covariantly*. How does your text do them?

Comment: (a) Why not compute the loop for arbitrary values of the external momenta to get a manifestly lorentz invariant answer, and then plug in the specific values you want later? (b) Just double checking you're aware that there should be three propagator factors in the loop, and you need to use momentum conservation at each vertex to determine which momenta appear in which propagator. (c) You didn't mention an external polarization factor for the photon. Normally you'd calculate this diagram with an external index, $M_\mu$, and you would need the Ward identity $k^\mu M_\mu=0$ (...)

Comment: (...) to ensure the result was gauge invariant. Are you planning to include the polarization factor directly into the calculation so you don't have a free $\mu$ index on the amplitude? (d) This diagram is computed in many textbooks, so there are references you can find with this calculation worked out in detail if you get stuck. For example, it is part of Srednicki's chapters on computing $g-2$ for the electron. (e) The diagram doesn't make sense as drawn... the bottom leg should be a photon and the left electron's arrow should be flipped.

Comment: Why are you numerically integrating? You’re just going to get infinity. The integral is divergent and must be regularized.

Comment: Andrew’s point (e) is your most serious issue. Do you understand that there is no fermion-fermion-fermion vertex in QED? Your diagram has two of them!

Comment: Apologies, I wanted to make a simple diagram to illustrate the situation. The inner circle is supposed to be a general 3-point function (ie a Veltman-Passarino C function), not three fermion lines. Consider it as shorthand for "any viable propagators". I cannot calculate analytically or work with arbitrary values, and I have not included the photon's polarization function, because this calculation is part of a bigger, more complex 2-loop integral. This was just a MWE to illustrate my current frustration.

Comment: And your integral is convergent? How?

Comment: In this particular part of the problem, I wick rotate and switch to 4-dimensional hyperspherical coordinates. The integration over the radius from 0 to $\infty$ converges. The problem is not the convergence, it's that my values are different depending on the frame of reference.

Comment: *Should $k$ have some predescribed form?* No. *The dot products ⋅ and ⋅ are different in the two frames.* No; $k$ is a 4-vector that transforms between frames just like the external momenta do; the dot products are invariant. The fact that $k$ gets integrated over doesn’t change the fact that it is a 4-vector.

Comment: @Ghoster we agree that there is no specific form for $k$ and that the dot products should be invariant. However, since $q$ and $l$ have different nonzero components in different frames, I don't see how the dot products can be invariant. In one frame, $q_0$ is the only nonzero element of $q$, so $q \cdot k$ depends only on $k_0$. In the other frame, $q_4$ is also nonzero, so the dot product depends on $k_0$ and $k_4$. Since the components of $k$ are independent integration variables, I don't see how I can correlate the dot products in the two frames.

Comment: *In one frame, $q_0$ is the only nonzero element of $q$.* You can’t have a real photon with no 3-momentum! $E=pc$ for a photon.

Comment: What’s going on with having indexes 0 and 4? Are you in 5D?

Comment: Your kinematic assumptions for case 2 were wrong. I haven’t looked carefully at case 1, because your use of $q_4$ at the beginning is wrong.